# Using endfloat with both sidewaystable and longtable

Tags: longtable, rotating, endfloat

I am attempting to use the endfloat package, whilst inputting tables from separate TeX files.

I've managed to use the following in the preamble, in order to allow endfloat to process sidewaystables, after loading in the rotating package:

```
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}
```

and this remedies the issue.

However, I've tried the same with respect to longtable but this doesn't seem to work. Is there any way of allowing both longtable and sidewaystable in the same document, to be processed by the endfloat package?

Comment: `sidewaystable` is incompatible with `longtable`. Try with `landscape` environment.

Comment: `endfloat` should work with `longtable` as well, see section 8.2
"Environments based on figures and tables" in the `endfloat`package documentation. So please be precise what you have tried (send code!), and what error message or erroneous result you get. "doesn't seem to work" is nothing we can base our help on.

Comment: @Bernard I don't think that `sidewaystable` is incompatible to `longtable`. It just makes no sense putting a `longtable` inside a `sidewaystable` environment.

Comment: @Axel Sommerfeldt: In what sense does it make no sense? I remember  having tried once, and it didn't wok, contrary to a `lansdcape` environment.