# Place long sidewaystable at the end of document(using endfloat with both sidewaystable/landscape and longtable)

Tags: longtable, rotating, landscape, endfloat

I have the same problem as described in this post: 
[Using endfloat with both sidewaystable and longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338812/using-endfloat-with-both-sidewaystable-and-longtable)

I would show a long table that goes over two pages and has a landscape orientation at the end of my paper.

To me it seems that 
 - sidewaystable works well with endfloat 
 - longtable works well within landscape
 - landscape does not work with endfloat
 - longtable does not work with sidewaystable.

Therefore, I am looking for a way how to combine endfloat, sidewaystable/landscape, and longtable.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[
  tablesonly,
  notablist,
]{endfloat}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}


\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{longtable}{table}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

\begin{table}
  \centering
    \caption{1st Table: Standard table}
            normal table works with endfloat
    \end{table}

\begin{longtable}{l}
    \caption{2nd Table: Longtable}\\
        longtable works with endfloat
        1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\  1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\  1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\
\end{longtable}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
    \caption{3rd Table: Sideways table}
      sidewaystable works with endfloat
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
        \caption{4th Table: Landscape}
        Landscape does not work with endfloat\\
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \begin{longtable}{l}
        \caption{5th Table: sidewaystable and longtable } \\
            sidewaystable and longtable do not work together
            1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\  1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\  1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{sidewaystable}


\section{Last section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `endfloat` package works by copying specific environments in their entirety into a ttt file (for tables).  So I create a new environment for a sideways `longtable` and added it to the list.

Note: `pdflscape` makes sideways text look rightside up, while `sidewaystable` does not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[
  tablesonly,
  notablist,
]{endfloat}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\newenvironment{longsidewaystable}[1]{\landscape\longtable{#1}}{\endlongtable\endlandscape}

\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{longtable}{table}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{longsidewaystable}{table}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

\begin{table}
  \centering
    \caption{1st Table: Standard table}
            normal table works with endfloat
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{l}
    \caption{2nd Table: Longtable}\\
        longtable works with endfloat
        1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\  1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\  1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\
\end{longtable}


\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
    \caption{3rd Table: Sideways table}
      sidewaystable works with endfloat
\end{sidewaystable}


\begin{longsidewaystable}{l}
    \caption{4th Table: Longtable}\\
        longsidewaystable works with endfloat
        1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\  1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\  1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\
\end{longsidewaystable}


\section{Last section}
\end{document}
```