# longtable with endfloat

Tags: longtable, endfloat

I got the following situation: I would like to place all tables in my document at the end. I found out that `endfloat` is usually used for this purpose.

`endfloat` puts a short reference at the position of each table location, something like "Table 1 about here..." for Table 1, etc. But it can lead to problems. For example I am also using `longtable` in my document. When I include a longtable somewhere, the positioning/table ordering at the end is always wrong. I am using the following code to accept longtables as floats:

```
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{longtable}{table}
```

The problem is that I got many tables and the longtable is placed at the beginning instead of where it should be, that is rather at the end. So it seems to mess up the order of tables (The labelling is correct though, just the order is affected). Is there any way to fix this in Latex? Or are there any alternatives to `endfloat`? Maybe people do this manually instead? Thanks for any hints.
I cannot make a working example because that would include a ton of tables.
edit: someone else had this problem, but it was not solved:
http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5554

edit: Here is the requested MWE. The problem only occurs if you also use sidewaystable.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=10pt, doublespacing, numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}           
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[nolists, tablesfirst]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\vspace{\floatsep}}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaysfigure}{figure}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{landscape}{table}       
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{longtable}{table}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section{Main part}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
A \\
\hline
a \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 1}
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{A simple longtable example}\\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are mixing up landscape and longtable.

Comment: There is still a landscape in the text. And make a minimal example -- there is no need for "tons of tables". Three should be enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @X7248724X: Did you try including `\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{longtable}{table}` in your preamble as described in section '8.2. Environments based on figures and tables' (page 9) of the `endfloat` package manual?

Comment: As I already wrote: Make an example. Without code one can only guess around.

Comment: I added the MWE

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388784/place-long-sidewaystable-at-the-end-of-documentusing-endfloat-with-both-sideway/388979?s=1|40.5519#388979

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks for the hint, but I do not want to create a new environment for a sideways longtable. I just want to prevent the longtable to mess up the table order created by endfloat, if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually one adds a `\clearpage` before `longtable` to flush queued floats, so I did.  Of course, the `\clearpage` has to be **inside** the environment in order to wind up in the `ttt` file.

The original `[h!tbp]` options work fine.  I just didn't bother to restore them.  Also, the `!` is pointless since `h` is attempted first anyway.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=10pt, doublespacing, numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}           
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[nolists, tablesfirst]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\vspace{\floatsep}}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaysfigure}{figure}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{landscape}{table}       

\let\normallongtable=\longtable
\renewcommand{\longtable}{\clearpage\normallongtable}

\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{longtable}{table}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section{Main part}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
A \\
\hline
a \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 1}
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{A simple longtable example}\\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```